# How to change notification dot color in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-notifications

How to change notification dot color in android Oreo.

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_white)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.accent))
```

I tried with setColor() but it is not working.

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by 'not working'? Any exception or error?

Comment: @vadimyarovikov - dot color is not changing. It is default app color.

Comment: @SnehPandya - I'm talking about dot on app icon in android O

Comment: @SnehPandya - Its not working

Answer (score 4):

> We cannot change the icon badge color for Android Oreo

Sadly we cannot change its color as right now, the badge icon color takes the apps icon color and that is the color we see for the badge icon.

Hopefully, I am wrong or I did not do enough research, but none of the following classes had a method to change the icon badge color:

- [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)
- [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html)
- [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)
- [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)
- [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)